# Explanation of asynchronous data loading in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Below the example code in a controller with 2 console.log instructions.
After accessing the page in browser, the list of users appears, all is displayed well. But the result of console.log is :

The first one: `after loadAll() function call = 0`

The second one: `End of loadAll() function = 8`

```
angular.module('tessicommunicationApp')
.controller('UserManagementController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$log', 'Principal', 'User', 'ParseLinks', 'Language', 'NgTableParams', function ($scope, $filter, $log, Principal, User, ParseLinks, Language, NgTableParams) {
            $scope.users = [];
            $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_TC_ADMIN", "ROLE_TC_GES_ADM", "ROLE_TC_SUI_TRA", "ROLE_TC_CONS"];
            Language.getAll().then(function (languages) {
                $scope.languages = languages;
            });

            Principal.identity().then(function (account) {
                $scope.currentAccount = account;
            });
            $scope.page = 1;
            $scope.loadAll = function () {
                User.query({
                    page : $scope.page - 1,
                    size : 20
                }, function (result, headers) {
                    $scope.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
                    $scope.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
                    $scope.users = result;
                    console.log("End of loadAll() function = " + $scope.users.length);
                });
            };

            $scope.loadPage = function (page) {
                $scope.page = page;
                $scope.loadAll();
            };
            $scope.loadAll();
            console.log("after loadAll() function call = " + $scope.users.length);
        }
    ]);
```

My question is simple : why the first one log print "0" whereas loadAll() method is called just before.

Answer (score 1):

Because the call is asynchronous, which in this case means the `$scope.users.lenght`has not yet been populated when you first log the length (`console.log("after loadAll() function call = " + $scope.users.length);`).
But in you "callback-function", when the data has been fetched in `$scope.loadAll()` you have recieved the data and `$scope.users` now has been populated.

Simply put, the code is executed directly after calling `$scope.loadAll()`, and does not wait for it to finish before running the next line `console.log("after loadAll() function call = " + $scope.users.length);`

Comment: ok thank you. And if I really want to force to print the length after having call loadAll() method, what should I do ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You're doing it right when you check the length in the callback, where you get the data. Before that, `$scope.users` will always be `0`

Comment: ok. I am thinking like in java. loadData is a function reusable. I call it and I expect the result (the return value...but here the users array is affected).

Answer (score 0):

For this you must have understanding how the javascript async(stack/task queue/event loop) works. Here you are making http call which is asychronous. The code for the call will be pushed to the task queue and the `console.log` after `loadAll` will be psuhed to the stack. As the stack things are executed on priority basis so the `console.log` after calling loadAll will be called first and once the stack gets empty and the result from the http call is returned, the things from the task queue are pushed to the stack by event loop for the furrther execution.